# Executable Jar limited to one window with JavaFX

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx-2, executable-jar, scenebuilder

I am building a JavaFX application through *E(fx)clipse* and *Java Scene Builder*.

The basic functionality is a login window.  Once logged in, new window opens and the login window disapears.  Right now it's just at the prototype stage.

When running out of ecplise, the functionality I want is all there.  Login window shows up on start (code looking as such)

```java
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("view/login.fxml"), ResourceBundle.getBundle("ca.sportstats.resources.labels"));

        primaryStage.setTitle("SportStats Live Update Tool : Login");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 450, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //Change this to open a small popup window.
        System.out.println("Could not deploy");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

There is one button on this window that simply opens another (the login logic will come later and not an issue here).

```java
    btnLogin.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

            //TODO: Login logic.
            //On success allow to open the tool (aka main window);

            Parent root;
            try {
                root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../view/selector.fxml"), resources);
                Stage stage = new Stage();
                stage.setTitle("Selector");
                stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 450, 450));
                stage.show();

                //hide this current window
                ((Node)(event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

This works no problem in Ecplise.  BUT!  When I build this (in the fashion described [on the e(fx)clipse tutorials](http://efxclipse.org/trac/wiki/Tutorial1#no1) I get an executable jar, but only get the login window.  When I click my button the *2nd* window doesn't show up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem I think is that in jars you can't do relative paths. Inside Eclipse you are running on the filesystem where this is not a problem

Comment: What would then be the *"base reference"*? Wouldn't this change whenever I change the location of the `.jar`?  And again, these files I am referencing are within the `.jar`, how would I absolutely point to that?  I might be missing something here...

Comment: This has nothing to do with your jar location! You are navigating within the jar! When I said relative paths this was not 100% correct because you can have relative paths but you can not have ".." in paths when resolving inside a jar.

You could use an absolute position inside your Classloader by using getClass().getClassloader().getResource("/my/view/selector.fxml") instead.

Comment: This was the knowledge I was missing.  Thanks for taking the time to explain it all out.

Comment: `FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(WindowManager.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/" + window + ".fxml"));` where `window` is the name identifier for the particular window .fxml file name. I have the same problem with the login menu not transite to the main menu. As you can see I have set the path as you said, but still the same issue. What detail am I missing?